# Normalize Space in HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

Here is the html snippet. How do I get normalize-space text ?

To search for the same fragment, but using Xpath `//*[normalize-space()='Text1 Text2']`

```
<div>
    <div>
        <a></a>
        <a></a>
        <div><a><span></span>Text2</a></div>
    </div>
        <div>Text2</div>
</div>
```

Using:

```
var htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("*");

foreach (var node in htmlNodes)
{
   text += node.InnerText;
}
```

I get this string:

```
"\r\n                        \r\n                        \r\n                        \r\n                        \r\n                        Text1\r\n                    Text2"
```

Can I get a normal text ?

```
"Text1 Text2"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `InnerText` property instead:

```
var texts = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Select(n => n.InnerText);
```

And combine them if you want:

```
var combined = string.Join(" ", texts);
```

To filter out empty values:

```
.Select(n => n.InnerText.Replace("\r\n", "")).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

Comment: there's not necessarily a first div, how do you specify any ?

Comment: Need to get the text of all DocumentNode

Comment: @Vipz then use document.DocumentNode.InnerText

Comment: All I knew is that I had before I do so, it does not solve my problem. I still see it in the text. "\r\n                        "

Answer (score 0):

If you're already at the node you need, and don't mind **all** white space turning into a single space character:

```
var htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
var normalized = Regex.Replace(htmlNodes.Trim(), @"\s+", " ");
```

A leaf-node search, this will keep whitespace within non-whitespace within an element unchanged (for example if you had `<div><a><span></span>this    needs    space</a></div>`):

```
var leafNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
    .Where(x => !x.ChildNodes.Any());
var trimmedInnerText = leafNodes.Select(x => x.InnerText.Trim())
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
var outputString = string.Join(" ", trimmedInnerText);
```

Comment: `Text1\r\n                    \r\n                    Text2`

Comment: Ahh, the `.SelectNodes("*")` ends up just selecting the outer-most element, forgot HAP would work like that.  To give you a full answer I'd need more context.  Thinking either a regex to replace any/all whitespace with a single space, or a depth-first search of the html document currently (will do those in edits now)